# jQuery close menu on button click with resize

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am working on a menu, that's using some jQuery to show or hide based on the width of the page. I almost have this working, just missing one little piece and I can't figure it out.

I have two menus, one is for small screens, the other for large screens. I am using css and jQuery to only show the specific menu I need based on screen size. I can resize page and the correct menu shows. When it's small, I can click on menu which shows an overlay. I can click close and the overlay closes. But when I resize the window again (after clicking close), the overlay shows again. So, the X is closing, but it's like my menu function is still running. What I am looking for, is when I click close then menu function no longer runs, almost as if it executes a page refresh without refreshing the page. Everything else is working. I'm guessing somehow instead of having a separate close function, it needs to be integrated into my existing menu code, so it's more like a toggle. Not sure how to tweak what I've got, so that it does that.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/joshrodgers/pen/eYxMwOR

```js
function menu() {
  var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html');
  $window.resize(function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 800) {
      $('.overlay').addClass('open');
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else {
      $('.overlay').removeClass('open');
      document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
    }
  }).trigger('resize');
}

function close() {
  $('.overlay').removeClass('open');
  document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
}
```

```css
/* Reset */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ol,
ul {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Overlay */

.overlay {
  background: rgba(99, 31, 43, 0.95);
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding-top: 69px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, visibility 0.2s;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 99999991;
}

.overlay .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay i {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay>ul>li:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.overlay ul li.current_page_item a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.overlay a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 15px 10px 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.overlay img {
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  .open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .open {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Nav */

#nav {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#nav ul {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  #nav>ul>li:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
  }
  #nav>ul>li:first-of-type i {
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #nav>ul>li:first-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
}

#nav li.current_page_item a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #631f2b;
  color: #631f2b;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#nav a {
  color: #a7a6a6;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 15px 10px 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="close">
    <a href="javascript:onclick=close()"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="javascript:onclick=menu()"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: From what I can see, you call the menu on click, which then attaches the menu functionality to the window resize event,  but it is never detached.  That would mean, after menu() has been called once, the resize event will keep calling that portion (not to mention attaching it again and again on each menu click) Maybe part of the code is missing? (also, the example doesn't seem to show the close button, but I only glanced at it, so might be missing something)

Answer (score 0):

On 'menu' click, the code to hide and show overlays is added to the window resize event. Not sure why, since it is also handled by css (hidding the overlay). But once it is added, it stays on the resize event, so any time width < 800, 'open' class is added to overlay again.
Since hiding overlay is already handled by the css resize, I think you can just ommit the entire resize event.

https://jsfiddle.net/kpw623av/

```js
function toggleMenu() {
    let show = $('.overlay').toggleClass('open');
  document.body.style.overflow = show ? 'hidden': 'visible';
}
```

```css
/* Reset */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Overlay */
.overlay {
    background: rgba(99, 31, 43, 0.95);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 69px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s, visibility 0.2s;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999991;
}

.overlay .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 20px;
}

.overlay i {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.overlay ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.overlay > ul > li:not(:first-of-type) {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.overlay ul li.current_page_item a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.overlay a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 15px 10px 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.overlay img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 0 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    .open {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .open {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Nav */
#nav {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#nav ul {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    #nav > ul > li:not(:first-of-type) {
        display: none;
    }
    #nav > ul > li:first-of-type i {
        margin-right: 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #nav > ul > li:first-of-type {
        display: none;
    }
}

#nav li.current_page_item a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #631f2b;
    color: #631f2b;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#nav a {
    color: #a7a6a6;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 15px 10px 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
            <div class="close">
                <a href="javascript:onclick=toggleMenu()"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="javascript:onclick=toggleMenu()"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ok, so with fresh eyes this morning I took a look at this. I removed the close class and added the toggleMenu class, which is a much simpler piece of code. The overlay works like a champ. The body overflow goes to hidden, but not back to visible when I click the close X in my overlay. I got the body to work by adding another toggle `('body').toggleClass('scroll')` and then added some css to show and hide using media queries. This is good, but is there some kind of tweak so that your `show : hide` works? I liked your solution better.

Comment: Not sure which part you mean, but in the html in the example, I simply had the close button call the same function ` <a href="javascript:onclick=toggleMenu()">`

Comment: Yes, I got that part :-) the close button does use the same function, the close button closes the overlay, but the body overflow stays hidden when it closes. When the overlay closes the scroll bar for the website should re-appear, but it stays hidden. Your code looks right because it’s supposed to toggle from visible to hidden then back to visible when closed and that doesn’t happen.